# Ajax Modal Only Works Once

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have an MVC application that uses a modal form to collect user information. There is a primary view with a dataTable, and each row in the dataTable renders a button that I use to render a partial view content inside the modal dialog. After a submission, the modal is supposed to disappear, so that the user could click on the same button or any other if they wanted to.

The problem I am having is that the buttons only click once. Specifically, when I click on one of the buttons, the form opens as expected and I can submit the changes to the database; that works no problem. After that, all of the buttons on that page do not do anything when I click on them.

Any ideas on what I can do to fix this issue?

Here is my code:

ORIGINAL VIEW:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <table id="NewCounterpartyRequests" class="display">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>                        
                        <th>Counterparty Legal Name</th>
                        <th>Requestor</th>
                        <th>View Details</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Counterparty Legal Name</th>
                        <th>Requestor</th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
                <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>

<div id='dialogDiv' class='modal fade in'>
    <div id='dialogContent'></div>
</div>
```

---

PARTIAL VIEW

```
<div id="dialogDiv" class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Counterparty Request Details</h3>
    </div>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditNewFullCounterpartyRequestDetails", "Counterparty",
        new AjaxOptions
        {
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            UpdateTargetId = "dialogDiv",
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            OnSuccess = "ShowSuccess"
        }))
{
<div>
        @Html.ValidationSummary()
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.RequestDetails.CounterpartyRequestId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.RequestDetails.CreatorUserId)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.RequestDetails.CounterpartyLegalName)

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
        </div>
}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetNewFullCounterpartyRequestDetails(int counterpartyRequestId)
    {
        FullCounterpartyRequestViewModel model = unitOfService.CreateFullCounterpartyRequestViewModel(counterpartyRequestId);
        model.ViewMode = "NEW";
        return PartialView("DisplayCounterpartyRequestPartial",model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditNewFullCounterpartyRequestDetails(FullCounterpartyRequestViewModel model)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //code to update the database
            return Json(new { success = true });
        }
        else
        {
            return PartialView("DisplayCounterpartyRequestPartial", model);
        }
    }
```

---

JAVASCRIPT

```
function ShowSuccess(result) {
    if (!result.success) {
        $('#dialogDiv').html(result);
    } else {
        alert('Thanks for submitting');
        $('#dialogDiv').modal('hide');
    }
};

$('.modal-dialog').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).find('.modal-body').css({
        'max-height':'100%'
    })});

$(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

    $('#NewCounterpartyRequests').on('click', '.ViewRequest', function (event) {
        var id = $(event.target).attr("data-id");
        var url = 'Counterparty/GetNewFullCounterpartyRequestDetails?counterpartyRequestId=' + id;
        $('#dialogContent').load(url, function () {
            $('#dialogDiv').modal('show');
        });
        return false;
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $('#NewCounterpartyRequests tfoot th').each(function () {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
    });

    //create a DataTable
    var table = $('#NewCounterpartyRequests').DataTable({
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "Counterparty/DisplayNewCounterpartyRequests",
    "bProcessing": true,
    "aoColumns": [
                    { "sName": "COUNTERPARTYLEGALNAME" },
                    { "sName": "REQUESTOR" },
                    {
                        "sName": "DETAILS",
                        "bSearchable": false,
                        "bSortable": false,
                        "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                            var id = full[2];
                            return '<button class="ViewRequest" data-id=' + id + '>View Details</button>';
                        }
                    }
    ]
    });

    // Apply the search
    table.columns().every(function () {
        var that = this;

        $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function () {
            if (that.search() !== this.value) {
                that
                    .search(this.value)
                    .draw();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out; essentially what was happening is that the .load method was targeting the dialogContent element, which gets wiped out when you load the partial view. As a result, I just changed that load method to load directly the dialogDiv element and simply removed the dialogContent element entirely. This now works.